# Calculate 95% Confidence Interval from Diagnostic Test Data

Tags: matlab, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the 95% confidence intervals based off a series of matrices based in Matlab:

[image: Matrix of Diagnostic Test Data]

I know how to calculate the required sensitivity, specificity, negative predictive value and positive predictive value, however I'm not sure, given these data, how to calculate the 95% confidence interval.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't say what value you want the 95% confidence interval of, but the data you've shown are not enough to calculate confidence intervals of anything. If you have more data behind what you've put in your post, please show it.

Comment: Then how are sites like this: http://vassarstats.net/clin1.html able to calculate confidence intervals given only the above data?

Comment: OK, reading the page you linked to (which you apparently haven't!), there's an explanation under the link 'Technical note'. I would be extremely cautious about quoting a confidence limit estimated in this way (and I would definitely call it an estimate not a calculation) unless I was confident I could defend the assumptions involved about the underlying distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You need the whole distribution to calculate your confidence intervals.
Once you have it, call it "data" and run the following code. 
The code works with nans in the data, with vectors (Nx1) or matrices (NxM). As long as each distribution is represented by a column

```
  %%% calculate CI
    alpha_lvl = [2.5 97.5]; % lower and upper boundaries for the CI 
    SEM = nanstd(data)./sqrt(sum(~isnan(data )));   % Standard Error
    ts  = tinv(alpha_lvl/100,length(data)-1);     % T-Score
    CI  = bsxfun(@plus,nanmean(data ),bsxfun(@times,SEM,ts')); % confidence intervals
```

Comment: Then how are sites like this: vassarstats.net/clin1.html able to calculate confidence intervals given only the above data?

Comment: this is not a matlab question no more, isn´t it?